# Sed \1 disappears

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to **sed** an htpasswd file line

`test:$y$j9T$WLGY.14lZu0BzrKsc6DCW.$QVsQJiEjSVhDpmOpUuYYw9/VE7ozGe92Y2FWapPAwK1`

When I do

```
user="test"
regexGrep="^$user"

$(cat ./.htpasswd | grep -E $regexGrep | sed -E "s/${user}:(.*)/\1/")
```

I get
`sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression`

Looks like the \1 disappears

In the same bash file, if I try this

```
regexSed="s@test:(.*)@\1@"
echo $regexSed

regexSed="s/${user}:(.*)/\1/"
echo $regexSed
```

I get these results

```
s@test:(.*)@@
s/test:(.*)//
```

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: `echo $regexSed` **should** have double quotes around the expansion: `echo "$regexSed"`

Comment: And don't use echo at all if you want consistent behavior around backslashes. `printf '%s\n' "$regexSed"` works consistently in __all__ POSIX-family shells.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: You are correct of course, that's what I demonstrated in the second version of the answer, but still this doesn't seem to explain why the `sed` command isn't working in the first example of the question. In my case it seems to work correctly regardless of the shell used.

Comment: `$(cat ... /\1/")` is trying to execute the result of `cat ... /\1/"`. Try without `$()`.

Comment: Please copy/paste your code into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it tells you about then ask here if you still have a question.

Comment: See also the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/q/77674344/1745001 which is trying to do something very similar.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Possibly you should escape the backslash in the double quoted string:</strike>

Use:

```bash
sed -E "s/${user}:(.*)/\\1/"
```

or

```bash
sed -E 's/'"${user}"':(.*)/\1/'
```

---

EDIT:

I believe that the problem has nothing to do with `sed` but instead it is with the shell's implementation of `echo`

See test below:

```bash
$ cat script.sh 
a='\1'
b='\\1'
echo "echo a: $a"
printf 'printf a: %s\n' "$a"
echo "echo b: $b"
printf 'printf b: %s\n' "$b"

$ bash script.sh 
echo a: \1
printf a: \1
echo b: \\1
printf b: \\1

$ sh script.sh 
echo a: 
printf a: \1
echo b: \1
printf b: \\1
```

Comment: My Bash and [online Bash](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P9FWPcZQnSsJSIHo1OSMfAUlMJlopaCSqMRVUJSZV5KmoA6lgaKqxTF56gpKIEkk5UlA5UkYypMQypOU/v8HAA) have a different result. Both `a` and `b` are printed as one would expect.

Comment: @dawg: In `bash` yes, that what I show in the answer. In `sh` I see different results though. My version is `GNU bash, version 5.2.15(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: I get the same result on Borne sh 3.2 == zsh == Bash 5.2. Hmmm

Comment: @dawg: It looks like on debian `sh` is `dash`, there I get similar output: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0kszvj/P9FWPcZQnSsJSIHo1OSMfAUlMJlopaCSqMRVUJSZV5KmoA6lgaKqxTF56gpKIEkk5UlA5UkYypMQypOU/v8HAA "Dash – Try It Online")

Comment: Sure enough! Dash seems to have an issue there. But the post here is for Bash and so this is likely not the issue for the OP, no?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you have no action on the result of the `$(command substitution)` so the output of that is then passed to the shell as a command.

Try:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'test:$y$j9T$WLGY.14lZu0BzrKsc6DCW.$QVsQJiEjSVhDpmOpUuYYw9/VE7ozGe92Y2FWapPAwK1' >htpasswd 

user="test"
regexGrep="^$user"

# rather that 'echo' you could have var=$(command) 
echo "$(grep -E $regexGrep htpasswd | sed -E "s/${user}:(.*)/\1/")"
```

As a simplification, you may want to use `sed` entirely to delete the prefix of the matching lines in the file rather than getting `grep` involved:

```
echo "$(sed -nE "s/^${user}://p" htpasswd)"
# same result...
```

With the addition of `-n` and `p` into sed, it is only printing the strings that match the regex after deleting the portion found.

---

With respect to the `echo` demo causing `\1` to disappear, this is not what is supposed to happen.

Inside double quotes, the `\` maintains its function of escaping the following character only for the characters '$', '`', '', or newline. See [HERE](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html)

In my Bash 5.2 and zsh:

```
regexSed="s@test:(.*)@\1@"
echo $regexSed   # You SHOULD double quote "$regexSed"
```

Prints:

```
s@test:(.*)@\1@
```

Try it online [here](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vyg1PbUiODXFVqnYoSS1uMRKQ09L0yHG0EGJKzU5I19BBaaAC8JX8ssvVygszS9JTbFS4uIipF0Jrl/p/38A)