# Remove line containing hostname with sed

Tags: bash, sed, scripting

I have a host with the hostname `babuntu10` and also `hostname12`, I want to remove only the hostname one from my `fstab` entry but the following `sed` command removes them both:

```
sed -i '/'"$HOSTNAME:"'/,$d' /etc/fstab
```

Input file:

```
babuntu10:/root/products/babuntu10 /root/products/babuntu10 nfs soft,timeo=1,retrans=1 0 0
babuntu12:/root/products/babuntu12 /root/products/babuntu12 nfs soft,timeo=1,retrans=1 0 0
```

I need to remove only the entry with the hostname.

Comment: What does `echo "$HOSTNAME"` print?

Comment: i guess your hostname is "babuntu10" and the form of "/regex/,$" match from the line matched /regex/ to the last line, not from start to end of a line. so if your hostname is "babuntu10", sed will delete the line containing "babuntu10" to the last line.  sed -i "/^$HOSTNAME/d" /etc/fstab

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sed '/x/,$d'` is asking sed to delete all lines from the first one that matches `x` till the end of the file. Sounds like you just want to delete the matching line so that'd be `sed '/x/d'` instead.

You should probably also add a start-of-string anchor `^` and use:

```
sed -i '/^'"$HOSTNAME"':/d' /etc/fstab
```

or, since the rest of your script is so brief and simple, you could just use double quotes around the whole thing:

```
sed -i "/^$HOSTNAME:/d" /etc/fstab
```

Comment: @anubhava I voted to reopen it but it's been deleted by some other people so I don't think that changed anything.

Comment: I did too now, didn't notice the undelete button previously.

Answer (score -1):

`sed -i "/${HOSTNAME}:/d" /etc/fstab`.
The key thing here, is that interpolation happens within double quotes, and the shell first iterpolates the command then passes this as argument to sed.

Comment: `sed -i '/'"$HOSTNAME:"'/,$d'` and `sed -i "/$(hostname)/d"` should do the same thing since `$(hostname)` will most likely be the same as `$HOSTNAME`. Replacing`,$d` with `d` looks like the solution  to the problem,so perhaps emphasize that?

Comment: Sorry, edited, I missed colon in the fstab entry.
I don't know if it should do the same, but seems a bit complex where it can be simpler.
In my example, I am indeed using the hostname command instead of the hostname environement variable, I can correct the example with the variable if you want.

Comment: I don't think `$(hostname)` is simpler than `$HOSTNAME`  but all the extra quotes in OPs example can be removed like you've done. The only problem I can see with OPs code is that `,$d` part.

Comment: yes, executing the hostname command or the hostname variable is not simpler, it's 2 different things (let me correct the command). The quotes are indeed simpler.  I think I don't understand the ",$d" part neither, and that was maybe the initial question ;)

Comment: The command is fine now but the explanation is still misleading.

Comment: this line sed -i '/^'"$HOSTNAME"':/d' /etc/fstab do the job but when i add it into playbook it ignore  : - name: Remove Line from FSTAB
                                    shell: sed -i '/^'"$HOSTNAME"':/d' /etc/fstab , nothing happen